# IEEETran and floating two column pictures

Tags: floats, ieeetran

I want to have a figure spanning two columns on the top of the page in the paper I am currently writing.

```
+-----------+
|  FIGURE   |       
|....  .....|
|....  .....|
|....  .....|
|....  .....|
|....  .....|
+-----------+
```

But the figure always gets a new page. I made a minimal working example using [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/SlothDWA.jpg) picture.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Some written stuff.
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\paperwidth]{figures/SlothDWA.jpg}
  \caption{Our architecture}
\end{figure*}
stufff stuff
More written stuff.
\end{document}
```

My result pdf looks like this:

```
+-----------+
|....  .....|       
|....  .....|
|....  .....|
|....  .....|
|....  .....|
|....  .....|
+-----------+
+-----------+
|           |       
|           |
|  FIGURE   |
|           |
|           |
|           |
+-----------+
```

Comment: figures are not allowed in the first page when you use `figure*` in two column.